# Laravel [5.2.21] Custom Auth Guard not persisting

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to set up a custom auth guard and everything is mostly working. I'm able to log the `Model` in, but once I redirect the visitor to a new page the authentication is lost. I can dd() the `Auth::guard('client')->user()` just fine before the controller does the redirect, but comes up as `null` in the `AuthenticateClient` middleware.

I'm using the default guard for authenticating users and everything is working fine with that. I've made sure the routes are under the `web` middleware which enables sessions.

I've searched for similar issues, but I'm unable to find a solution that works. Any ideas how to fix this?

Side note: I know that I'm using `token` in the code examples below, but I'm doing more than just validating against that token. So this is a different system than authenticating a token for an api.

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // other routes...

    Route::get('client/login/{token}', ['as' => 'client.token', 'uses' => 'Auth\ClientController@attemptTokenLogin']);

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'middleware' => 'auth.client'], function () {
       Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'client.dashboard',  'uses' => 'ClientController@dashboard']);
    });
});
```

**auth.php**

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        // new auth guard
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // new guard provider
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    // new...
    'auth.client' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateClient::class,
];
```

**ClientController@attemptTokenLogin**

```
$client = // get the client in a custom way...
Auth::guard('client')->login($client);

// dd(Auth::guard('client')->user()); // this works here

return redirect()->route('client.dashboard');
```

**AuthenticateClient**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // dd(Auth::guard('client')->user()); // this does not work here

    if (!Auth::guard('client')->check()) {
        return redirect()->route('client.login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: In the `providers` array you've used `clients` but the guard is `client`.

Comment: that is working as expected. the guard is named `client` but the provider is named `clients`, which the guard is pointing to the correct one. However, even when changing the provider to `client`, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When implementing `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` I was not returning `getAuthIdentifierName()` or `getAuthIdentifier()`

so...

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    $this->getKeyName();
}

public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    $this->getKey();
}
```

was supposed to be...

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return $this->getKeyName();
}

public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
```

Comment: 15 hours straight trying to figure out how to solve this... Funny thing is, this question was the first I visited but ignored by its simplicty... 15 hours later, after I figured out the problem by myself after studying the whole framework and its request cycle, I recalled this question... If only I tried this at first, I'd save 15 hours of useless headaches.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to add `web` middleware to your routes. Since 5.2 this is the default behavior

Comment: 3 days. That's how long this issue tortured me for.

Comment: I'm working on Laravel 5.4 , for me the same issue persists, can you please guide  me in where to modify the above code.

Comment: @ReiahPaulSam this was on my new `App\Client` model class.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you